# What meaning does the sentence in bold convey?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

It requires no design or desire on the part of an actor to act his part, whereto he is led by the tenor of his prior propensities (of past lives); as a potter’s wheel is propelled by the pristine momentum, without requiring the application of continued force for its whirling motion. **So O sinless Rama! mind our actions to be under the direction of our previous impressions, and not under the exertion of our present efforts.**

Should Rama act in accordance with his previous impressions or the exertions of his present efforts?

From [verse 7.1.9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc267552.html) of [Yoga Vasistha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Vasistha).
<sub>English translation by Vihari-Lala Mitra (1891)</sub>

Comment: It is not an instruction to Rama, but a request for Rama to guide ***us*** into acting from our past knowledge, and not be distracted by the immediacy of a situation.

Comment: I was about to vote to close this as off-topic, but refrained from doing so, because I see that the balance of the existing votes would result in the question being migrated to ELL, where it would, I fear, cause a great deal of confusion.

Comment: Probably should be migrated to [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you are interested only in understanding the passage (rather than analysing the use of English language that it exemplifies), you should consult another translation.

Answer (score -2):

This hangs on the meaning of *mind*. In this context it is a verb. When prefixed by the exclamatory “*O Rama*” (a vocative), it becomes a command or request.

> To mind = to remember a piece of information when you are making a decision or thinking about a matter
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mind)

> Vocative. The imperative is often used with a vocative. This is where you mention a person’s name or some other way of identifying the person to whom a command or request is being addressed.
>
> [Collins dictionary](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/direct-and-indirect-objects)
> David, come here!

Hence, the bold prose is a request to Rama to recognise that our actions are directed by previous experience and not by our present circumstance.

**Edited**. Comments persuade me that there is an ambiguity here.

It has been argued that Rama is a god (this is additional context) and that Rama may not be commanded. However, it is often the cases that gods are prayed to (=requested rather than commanded) in terms of command. For example, in Christianity we have "Lead us not into temptation". That being so, my interpretation stands.

The argued alternative is that "*mind our actions ...*" = "*please influence us to ...*", which seems an odd sort of request - to ignore the present in favour of the past.

Comment: *To mind* is not used here in the sense captured by the quoted definition, but in the sense of *to take care of* (as in 'minding the children').

Comment: @jsw29 I think not. Rama is not requested to look after anything; he is requested to "keep something in mind" . I stand by my interpretation.

Comment: I am with @jsw29 here. Rama is a god, and you don't tell a god what to do, but pray that this perfect god (O sinless Rama) will look after you, and keep you mindful of what you know you should do, and not be distracted: dharma.

Comment: I see your points and have tried to accommodate them in my edit.

Comment: The last sentence of the edit shows that you have not understood the text at all. The point is that the past, with Rama's help, will get you through the present time in the right way.

Comment: There is no “right” way implied. All that is referred to, particularly in the case of the potter’s wheel metaphor, is the predetermined way. I am concerned with the English and not so much with speculative meaning.

Comment: Exegesis of religious texts heavily depends on the wider context; it is risky to try to interpret a short passage from such a text in isolation. The risk is compounded if one is looking at the passage only in translation, and compounded yet further if the translation is relatively old.